# How to place a C struct on the function stack in Rust?

Tags: c, struct, rust

I would like to transfer the following C code

```c
HMAC_CTX context;
HMAC_CTX_init(&context);
```

into Rust. But while it's easy to define an extern function, it seems impossible to directly use a C struct in Rust.

```rust
extern "C" {
  use HMAC_CTX; // does not work!
  fn HMAC_CTX_init(ctx: *mut HMAC_CTX);
}
```

I know that I could define a placeholder struct in Rust

```rust
struct HMAC_CTX;
```

...but an instance of may not hold enough space for the real C struct.

```rust
let mut ctx = HMAC_CTX;
unsafe { HMAC_CTX_init(&mut ctx); }
```

Is there a way of solving this without redefining the whole struct in Rust? That would create a dependency from the external code to my Rust project and I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Most people use [`rust-bindgen`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen). Would that solve your issue?

Comment: "I know that I could define a placeholder struct in Rust" that's not a placeholder struct, it's an *empty struct*, sometimes called "unit struct". Despite looking similar, *it has nothing in common with C's struct declaration*.

Comment: Thanks for a fast answer! It'd probably solve the problem, but I'd like to avoid a code generator. It feels a bit much for this simple function call.

Comment: " But while it's easy to define an extern function, it seems impossible to directly use a C struct in Rust." of course. The extern declaration provides the signature of the function to call but at the fundamental level they're not related. For structs, the signature is *the entire struct definition*.

Comment: "It'd probably solve the problem, but I'd like to avoid a code generator." Well then you get to codegen it by hand: copy/paste the original, tag it as `repr(C)` and fix the divergences in types and all.

Comment: You can write the equivalent Rust code by hand, as a `#[repr(C)]` struct, but you have to be careful and keep the definitions syncrhonized. I've done that for simple C modules of my own.

Comment: Although I don't see why you wouldn't just use the existing openssl bindings which do all the hard work for you, assuming you want all of openssl (if you just want to compute hmac, then RustCrypto's implementations would probably be simpler).

Comment: Yeah, my question was more if there is a better way than copy/paste the code?

Comment: @Masklinn I used the OpenSSL binding just as an example here. The same issue occur in other parts the code too.

Comment: Better way one is using existing bindings (openssl-sys or the higher-level openssl crate), better way two is using bindgen. I'm not aware of a better way 3.

Comment: `HMAC_CTX` is an opaque structure. It's layout and contents never surface in client code. It is only ever used as `HMAC_CTX*`, i.e. a pointer. As such, it is not required for your client (Rust) code to understand its internals. To client code, this is just a pointer to *some* data controlled by OpenSSL.

Comment: @IInspectable That is true for OpenSSL 1.1.0, but 1.0.2 does not have this kind of constructor. But this question was really not about OpenSSL. It's used just as an example here.

Comment: I'll summarize some of the comments to answers

Answer (score 1):

Use `rust-bindgen` to generate Rust bindings. It'll generate a rust version of the corresponding C struct and keep it synchronized if placed in the build-script.

Adds complexity to the build process and adds a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Rust version of the C struct by hand.

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct HMAC_CTX {
  md: *mut EVP_MD,
  md_ctx: EVP_MD_CTX,
  i_ctx: EVP_MD_CTX,
  o_ctx: EVP_MD_CTX,
  key_length: c_uint,
  key: [c_uchar; 128],
}
```

This requires to follow changes of the C code and manually update the Rust struct. Also further structs might have to be defined. Add a dependency to the internals of the called library :-(

Comment: If you need a quick way to translate C code into (unsafe) Rust code as a starting point you can use [C2Rust](https://c2rust.com/). It's a web based frontend to the [c2rust](https://github.com/immunant/c2rust) transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

Create a placeholder struct.

```rust
pub struct HMAC_CTX {
  _placeholder: [c_uchar; 256],
}
```

This struct needs to be large enough to hold all the internals of the C struct. Indirect dependency :-( If the C struct size exceeds the placeholder size, it could lead to unsafe behavior.

Comment: The struct must also have the same alignment as the C struct. If the alignment is stricter in Rust you can invoke undefined behavior when passing pointers from C to Rust. If the alignment is stricter in C you can invoke undefined behavior going the other way.